# Select text with Shift+Alt+Arrow

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way in phpstorm to select text like this and past the code behind.

[image: selecting text]

at the moment my selecting looks like this:
[image: text-selection]

but i wan it like this without editing the whole lines themself:

[image: selected text]

I looked at other answers here on SO, but didn't find what im searching for.
I've tried to use 
**Edit | Column Selection Mode** and **Shift+Alt+Insert** but it wont work. It will only let me select the text.

Comment: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/multicursor.html?search=multi 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+for+Users+of+Text+Editors#PhpStormforUsersofTextEditors-Multiplecaretsandselections/Sublime-styleMultipleColumns

Comment: @LazyOne thanks :) saved me so much time on searching the web